# Windows 7 Toolbar does not move with Taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, notifications, toolbar, quicklaunch

So I have a quick launch toolbar on the right side of taskbar at the bottom of my screen in Windows 7 (it is a Recycle Bin shortcut). However when new programs add an icon in the notification area on the right side, the toolbars (the quick launch recycle bin, along with my language toolbar) shift over to the left. If a notification icon disappears, the language toolbar moves to the rightmost position on the taskbar with the notification area, but the quicklaunch toolbar does not. It just floats out on the taskbar. This can be frustrating because I open and close multiple programs during the day, pushing my recycle bin out farther and farther. Anyone know how to fix this?